# ASP.Net Session Timeout Scenario

Tags: asp.net

We are working on an application that stores user entered data in a session object.  The application is a type of wizard, if the user's session times out we want to display a message and send the user to the start of the wizard again.

How can I best do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The best [dreamincode "blog"](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45300-base-page-for-detecting-session-timeout-in-aspnetc%23/) explaining a base page solution for session timeout.

Here is a quick and dirty way ([codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/45175/Session-Timeout-Notification.aspx)), which basically just uses a client side script.

A more detailed one with words [Session.Timeout and Notification Before Session Expire](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/01/05/118269.aspx)(same type of solution client side script).